# File compression with C++

Tags: c++, compression

I want to make my own text file compression program. I don't know much about C++ programming, but I have learned all the basics and writing/reading a file. 
I have searched on google a lot about compression, and saw many different kind of methods to compress a file like LZW and Huffman.  The problem is that most of them don't have a source code, or they have a very complicated one. 
I want to ask if you know any good webpages where I can learn and make a compression program myself?

EDIT:
I will let this topic be open for a little longer, since I plan to study this the next few days, and if I have any questions, I'll ask them here.

Comment: Use or read the code from zlib: http://zlib.net/ for a good start.  this is a very hard problem.

Comment: So you want to write your own, but you want a source-code implementation of the compression algorithm to start with rather than implementing it yourself from an algorithm description?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most of the algorithms are pretty complex. But they all have in common that they are taking data that is repeating and only store it once and have a system of knowing how to uncompress them (putting the repeated segments back in place)

Here is a simple example you can try to implement.

We have this data file

> XXXXFGGGJJ
>
> DDDDDDDDAA
>
> XXXXFGGGJJ

Here we have chars that repeat and two lines that repeat. So you could start with finding a way to reduce the filesize.

Here's a simple compression algorithm.

> 4XF3G2J
>
> 8D2A
>
> 4XF3G2J

So we have 4 of X, one of F, 3 of G etc.

Comment: Run-Length Encoding! Works well for images with lots of uniform colors (it was used by IFF-ILBM and BMP), but not that useful for text, given that you rarely ever have more than two consecutive occurrences of the same character.

Comment: Aye but a great example to start with :)

Comment: RLE is probably the best compression algo to get started with since it is so simple (you can write it in an afternoon).

Comment: I guess what you are showing works best for images, but thanks anyway, since I plan to make image compression program later.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this [page](http://koti.kapsi.fi/a1bert/Dev/pucrunch/packing.html) it contains a clear walk through of the basics of compression and the first principles.

Answer (score 3):

Compression is not the most easy task. I took a college class to learn about compression algorithms like LZW and Huffman, and I can tell you that they're not that easy. If C++ is your first language and you're just starting into this sort of thing, I wouldn't recommend trying to write your own sorting algorithm just yet. If you are more experienced, then I would try writing source without any code being provided to you - this shows that you truly understand the compression algorithm.

This is how I was taught - the professor explained the algorithm in very broad terms, and then either we would implement it (in Java, mind you) or we would answer questions about how the algorithm would behave under certain circumstances. If we could do either of those, then we really knew the algorithm - without him showing us any source at all - it's a good skill to develop ;)

Answer (score 1):

Huffman encoding tree's are not too complicated, I'd start with them.  Here's a link: [Example: Huffman Encoding Trees](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node41.html)